# Restoring purchases in swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

So i can't seem to get the `updatedTransactions` protocol to fire when trying to restore purchases.

I have a button in one view controller which calls the following method in my IAPViewController file `restoreIAP()` which is set up like so.

```
func restoreIAP(){

    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().restoreCompletedTransactions()
}
```

This method is called when the user presses the button so this is the class which handles this.

```
class SettingsViewController: IAPViewController {


    @IBAction func restoreDidTouch(sender: AnyObject) {

        restoreIAP()
        activityTitle = "Restoring"

    }

}
```

In my `IAPViewController` nothing seems to be triggering this method so that i can do something.

```
// Check the transaction
func paymentQueue(queue: SKPaymentQueue, updatedTransactions transactions: [SKPaymentTransaction]) {

    // Check the tranactions

    for transaction in transactions {

        switch transaction.transactionState {

        case .Purchasing:
            // TODO: Start Activity Indicator
            showPurchaseIndicator(activityTitle)
            break

        case .Purchased:
            // TODO: End the purchasing activity indicator
            dismissPurchaseIndicator()
            print("Transaction completed successfully.")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            transactionInProgress = false

            // TODO: Put method here to unlock all news sources
            storiesMethods.unlockAllStories()
            break

        case .Restored:
            // TODO: Start Activity Indicator
          //  showPurchaseIndicator(activityTitle)
            break

        case .Failed:
            dismissPurchaseIndicator()
            notificationMethods.showAlertErrorMessage(self, title: "Purchase", actionMessage: "Dismiss", message: "Unable to complete transaction please try again later.")
            SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().finishTransaction(transaction)
            transactionInProgress = false
            break

        default:
            print(transaction.transactionState.rawValue)
            break
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Did your controller added as observer using `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addTransactionObserver(..)`?

PS: Have a look at [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit)  ( [InAppProductPurchaseRequest.swift](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit/blob/master/SwiftyStoreKit/InAppProductPurchaseRequest.swift) )

Comment: Looking at that library i think i'll try and implement this framework in my app looks a lot more robust

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the code snippets it looks like everything is in the right order.

If the `paymentQueue` function is never called, your `IAPViewController` probably doesn't conform to the `SKPaymentTransactionObserver` protocol, just make it conform:

`class IAPViewController: UIViewController, SKPaymentTransactionObserver`

and you're good to go.